# Sharing xml and data between multiple projects

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, resources

I have three projects(C# libraries) namely A,B,C.
All the 3 have 3-4 xml files(in general can be resources) associated with them.
Each of these projects have classes that access these files for settings and information.
(loading xmls when ever they need)

The problems is sometimes there is a need that a class in project C may need to access
resources(xml files,images etc) of project B and vice versa.

Also these files may or may not be  a part of the project solution.These resource paths 
can come from app.config etc.

Its really becoming tedious to work out how to centralise access to these resources so that
all three projects can access them uniformly.

Currently all the projects load the files using app.config.

Also i'm trying to minimise the number of times a xml is loaded.(ideally once).
But given the projects are different i have to load it again.

I thought of using a Singleton class as it would make more sense for making uniform access but haven't quiet figured out a way.

Anyone has come across similar situations?
Are there any design patterns or best practices for sharing resources across projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one library containing the class(es) that access your centralized XML settings, and reference that library from the other libraries.

You don't necessarily need a Singleton for this, but putting it in one place will allow you to focus your efforts on things to improve it later, possibly caching, etc.